# PHP code that splits the file name, and rename it with contents in the file

Tags: php

I have many files, and some of which contain "5010" in there name, usually when I see these numbers, I open the file and get the code next to the name REF and paste it instead of the 5010, and send it to the server, however I'm suppose to do it through a php script that would be able to do this task on its own, Any ideas on where to start with this?

For example my file name is

```
"hasdbgf.5010.dfgur.fde"
```

I want to remove the "5010", so I open the file:

```
DTM*405*2022~
N1*PR*AEA~
N3*151 AVENUE~
N4*06156~
REF*2U*60054~
```

I see that after REF*2U is "60054", so I rename it:

```
"hasdbgf_60054_dfgur.fde"
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois I edited it, please take a look

Comment: Use a loop and an array of filesnames to rename. In the loop use `file_get_contents` to get the contents of the file, use Regex (`preg_match`) to get the number and then rename the file with `rename` (use `str_replace` or `preg_replace` to replace the part of the filename). For function reference, visit http://php.net

Comment: Honestly, I don't even know where to start I just have a few functions but I haven't tired if they would work or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have wrote this script in 5 minutes. Just put it inside your directory where you would like renaming operation to be done. That is all.

```
//expression to be found in file name
$find = '.5010.';

//directory name
//we will store renamed files here
$dirname = 'renamed_5010';
if(!is_dir($dirname))
    mkdir($dirname, 0777);

//read all files from a directory
//skip directories
$directory_with_files = 'C:\dir\path';
$dh  = opendir($directory_with_files);
$files = [];
while (false !== ($filename = readdir($dh)))
{
    if(in_array($filename, ['.', '..']) || is_dir($filename))
        continue;

    $files[] = $filename;
}

//iterate collected files
foreach($files as $file)
{
    //check if file name is matching $find
    if(stripos($file, $find) !== false)
    {

        //open file
        $handle = fopen($file, "r");
        if ($handle)
        {
            //read file, line by line
            while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false)
            {

                //find REF line
                if(stripos($line, 'REF') !== false)
                {
                    //we are going to REF line reverse
                    $reverse = strrev($line);
                    $found = false;
                    $refnumber = [];

                    //find reference number
                    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($reverse); $i++)
                    {

                        if(is_numeric($reverse[$i]))
                        {
                            $found = true;
                            $refnumber[] = $reverse[$i];
                        }

                        if($found == true && !is_numeric($reverse[$i]))
                            break;
                    }

                    //glue refernce numbers
                    //check if reference number is not empty
                    $refnumber = strrev(join('', $refnumber));
                    if(!empty($refnumber))
                    {
                        $refnumber = '_' . $refnumber . '_';
                        $filerenamed = str_replace($find, $refnumber, $file);
                        copy($file, $dirname . '/' . $filerenamed);
                    }

                    echo $refnumber . "\n";
                }
            }

            //close file
            fclose($handle);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do I need to put the line, where the $refnumber will be found?

Comment: It will find line of $refnumber by itself. Just run this script, it will do all of the work for you.

Comment: I put my directory name $dirname= 'C:\Desktop\835file';  where you have the \\file name right?

Comment: Yes, C:\Desktop\835file if this is your folder containing files you want to rename, thats all you need to setup. Actually let me add that path to the code, so you don't get confused.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122002/discussion-between-jazzyy22-and-asmir-zahirovic).